# Update array list with a property issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, promise

I am trying to update the array list for user in the `userList`... to have a property called valid if `userDetails.length` is not zero.

But the userList never gets updated.

```
userList.map(async function(user) {
    let userId = user.id
    await db.queryUser(userId)
      .then(function(userDetails){
        if(userDetails.length !== 0){
          user.valid = true;
        }
    });
});
```

I tried doing this:

```
let filteredList = userList.map(async function(user) {
    let userId = user.id
    await db.queryUser(userId)
      .then(function(userDetails){
        if(userDetails.length !== 0){
          user.valid = true;
        }
    });
});
```

but the promise stays pending. Any better way to this?

**UPDATE**

Got it to work using the following code:

```
await Promise.all(userList.map(async function(user) {
    let userId = user.id
    await db.queryUser(userId)
      .then(function(userDetails){
        if(userDetails.length !== 0){
          user.valid = true;
        }
    });
  })
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The promises are pending because you never await for them. You are just creating a map of promises.

If you want to update the users in place, you don't need a map for that:

```js
for (let user of userList) {
   const userDetails = await db.queryUser(user.id);
   if (userDetauls.length) user.valid = true;
}
```

(assuming the outer function is async, otherwise use `.then` instead of `await`)

**UPDATE**
Well, this will, however, execute the queries in a serial manner. Maybe you want them to run in parallel.

In that case, you may want to actually do the map, but then await the promises using `Promise.all`.

Something like this: `await Promise.all(userList.map(...));`

Comment: user return an int sometimes instead of the object... but the object does exist in userList and print fine. Why would that be?

Comment: What do you mean by "user return an int"? And what is sometimes? When? Are you talking about the for...of loop?

Comment: Got it to work. Thanks! One last question, should I use await with Promise.all() and the promise calls inside it? Please see my edit on the question

Comment: `await` is just some syntactic sugar for `.then`, so you only need one of the two options. You can either write `const userDetail = await db.queryUser()` or `db.queryUser().then(userDetail => ...)`, both will work. If you do `await db.queryUser().then(...)`, it will work too because the `then` returns a Promise too, but it is unnecessary. About `Promise.all`: it returns a promise. You need to wait until it resolves, that's why you need to `await` it or use `.then` on it. So it's up to you if you want to use await or then, with one exception: you can only use `await` inside `async` function.

Comment: One more thing: It would be better if the `map` didn't update the users, it's a surprising side-effect (like if calling a getSomething() would update something - you wouldn't expect it). Maybe you should load the userDetails first, something like `const userDetails = await Promise.all(userList.map(user => db.queryUser(user))` and only then use the userDetails to update the users. Note that the map function now doesn't need to by async, it just returns the promises from the queryUser.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like you are trying to use async/await syntax **with** the .then syntax instead of in place of it. Try storing the response into the variable userDetails when you call your queryUser function then do your check on the length like so:

```
let filteredList = userList.map(async function(user) {
    let userId = user.id
    let userDetails = await db.queryUser(userId)

    if(userDetails.length !== 0){
          user.valid = true;
        }
});
```